# Connecting to URL using proxy in FOP API

Tags: java, apache-fop

We are using FOP API to convert content into PDF. Everything works as expected except image conversion.
Image should be connected through proxy as we are behind proxy. I couldn't find option in the API documentation (we are using FOP 2.3 version) to pass proxy for connecting to the url.

Configuration in xsl: "external-graphic src="url('{imageUrl}')"

Could you please help me in achieving this.
Regards,
Vinay

Comment: This was handled in java code to bypass proxy when populating the image.